# how to execute a program before user login

Tags: windows, login, scheduled-tasks

i have a program that i want to execute as soon as windows starts and before user log in
or can i disable user login until my program is executed

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614(VS.85).aspx).